# mysql joining for relational lookup

Tags: mysql

I've never been all that great with much more then regular select queries. I have a new project that has `users`, `roles` and `assigned_roles` (lookup table for users with roles).

I want to group_concat the `roles`.`name` so that my result shows me what roles each user has assigned.

I've tried several things:

```
select users.id, users.displayname,users.email, rolenames from `users` 
left join `assigned_roles` on `assigned_roles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
left join (SELECT `id`, group_concat(`roles`.`name`) as `rolenames` FROM `roles`) as uroles ON `assigned_roles`.`role_id` = `uroles`.`id`
```

This gives me the grouped role names but shows me duplicate entries if a user has two roles, so the second row in the result shows the same user but no role names.

```
select users.id, users.displayname,users.email, rolenames from `users` 
join `assigned_roles` on `assigned_roles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
join (SELECT `id`, group_concat(`roles`.`name`) as `rolenames` FROM `roles`) as uroles ON `assigned_roles`.`role_id` = `uroles`.`id`
```

Just regular joins shows me what I want but wont lists users who do not have any `assigned`.`roles`, so its not complete.

I'll keep plugging away but I thought stack could help, hopefully I'll learn a bit more about joins today.

Thank you.

Comment: please add some data with table on http://sqlfiddle.com and expected result to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `GROUP CONCAT` to work in this scenario, you'll need a `GROUP BY` to get the group info per user, something like;

```
SELECT u.id, u.displayname, u.email, GROUP_CONCAT(r.name) rolenames 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN assigned_roles ar ON ar.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = ar.role_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.displayname, u.email
```